# Нужно найти объект, на котором некая картинка с url(именно поиск по url картинки)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

платежные методы постоянно меняются, поэтому нужно привязка чисто по локатору не получается, нужно привязаться по названию картинки http://prntscr.com/n1e4pl

```
public IWebElement CashboxPopupTakeMethodQiwi => Driver.WaitUntilVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='payments -in -form'], 
'background-image: url(https://vipnetgame.com/themes/cash/uploads/cash/qiwi.png?v=2.1));')]"));
```

даная реализация не находит. Подскажете как будет правильно

Comment: Что это? и кто кого не находит? и чем?

Comment: Selenium, мне нужно найти обэкт и кликнуть по нему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте искать с помощью такого xPath:
`//*[contains(@style, 'qiwi.png')]`

Здесь `contains` - команда для поиска частичного совпадения.

`@style` - то, где мы ищем. background-image хранится в атрибуте style, именно поэтому мы там его и ищем.

`'qiwi.png'` - та часть, по которой мы пытаемся найти совпадения (потом, для других картинок платёжных систем, меняйте это значение)